# Fetch all users initially or on Search?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In order to invite others to one's group they must search for their target by name or email, then all matches are placed in a table. Right now I'm retrieving all the users from my Firebase database when the invites page initially loads but I'm concerned that if many users sign up it could become an unnecessarily large upfront data fetch.

Is it better to just fetch users based off each search or to fetch all of them at the start?

Comment: Any reason why you would want all the users upfront?

Comment: It makes individual searches faster when there aren't that many users since all the data is already local.

Comment: I'd use something like `startAt(searchTerm).limitToFirst(10)` to get the first 10 names that start with what the user typed. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data